# Seeking Python GDAL documentation?

Tags: python, gdal, documentation

Is there an official documentation for the python GDAL module?

There are various cookbooks, but scant information on each function or arguments for the most basic functions.

Comment: For advanced Python users I found the [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) documentation (in combination with the source code for examples) to be a good starting place. They have a good documentation and basically try to provide a more pythonic wrapper for GDAL with close to 100% coverage of the GDAL Python API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [python API documentation](http://gdal.org/python/), but there's little explanation of arguments, outputs, etc. I use it in tandem with the [c++ API documentation](http://www.gdal.org/hierarchy.html), the [source code](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal) and the [tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) to figure things out. But a single python documentation source would be nice...

Comment: I'd also include the [GDAL Python Gotchas](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas) into this list, which explain the most common errors when using the Python API.

Comment: This is an old entry. Any updates?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Not that I'm aware of anyway.